# Industry robot maximum torque

Tags: motor, research

In google search, I find Abb industry robot wrist maximum torque is around 6000Nm, So I’m wondering, in most industry robot, how much the maximum torque can reach? In another words, which motor is advance and can provide the best torque in industry robot. Thank you very much!
Best,
Ben

Comment: here is an old article about a robot that develops 125,268 kNm of torque .... not the kind of robot that you are talking about, but still interesting ... https://tunnelbuilder.com/News/Mega-TBM-for-Madrid-M-30.aspx

Comment: Thank you, that is amazing！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to generate the high levels of torque you are referring to, the actuator will certainly require a transmission of some sort.  Above 500 Nm, cycloidal rather than harmonic drives are employed, usually preceded by a planetary input stage.

Nabtesco, in Japan, is probably the current industry leader in these type of drives, which it brands as "RV" drives.  Looking at Nabtesco's product line, the highest repeatable torque available comes from the RV-500C line - around 12,250 Nm.  The Nabtesco website also has a [product selector](https://precision.nabtesco.com/en/products/select/) where you can explore different manufacturers' motor options.